# How to remove the last character in the column in power query excel?

Tags: excel, powerquery

[image]

I want to remove the last character of the column, `K` and `M`. So that I'm able to add another column such that if the last character is `M` then the number x 1000000 else the number x 100000. What can I do?

The screenshot below is the step that already been applied to the table:

[image]

Comment: Will r-click (on the input), format cells, Number > Custom : 0 do the trick ?

Comment: You mean doing in excel right? Is there any other method that allow me to do it in power query?

Comment: yup (coz I see `excel` tag there). sorry, I don't have access to Power Query. I'm not sure if this will help : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To just remove the last character you can use `Text.RemoveRange`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.RemoveRange([Query],Text.Length([Query])-1))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

To convert strings ending in `K` or `M` to their real numbers, you can do things a bit more complex:  *(Note that I assumed `K=1000` and `M=1000000` to be consistent; other systems have `M=1000` and `MM=1000000`. I am not aware of a system where `K=100000` but you can easily edit the code if you need to)*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Query", type text}}),
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
        let 
            x = Text.End([Query],1),
            y = Number.From(Text.RemoveRange([Query],Text.Length([Query])-1)),
            result =    if x = "K" then y * 1000 
                   else if x = "M" then  y * 1000000

/*Note that code assumes that if string doesn't end with K or M
  it is a number. You may want to test specifically for that to avoid errors*/
  
                   else Number.From([Query])
        in 
            result, type number)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

If you are having trouble entering the code, you can add it as a custom column to your existing code. Be sure to change the column identifier in the code to whatever the column name is in your code that references the table you show. Possibly `[Query.Avg Volume]`

eg:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfeld, thanks for your reply and effort. I'm quite new to M code. I'm not sure where to add in the code in the advance editor as there are some lines of code inside already. I edited my question together with the code that already exist in advance editor, hope to get your help, thanks!

Comment: @Elvis I have added a screenshot showing how you can add the relevant code as a custom column. Also, I noticed you posted your MCode as a screenshot, so I did the same with the custom column code. Do you prefer that to text?

Answer (score 0):

With the M-Code below the following input table

[image]

is expanded to this

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Avg", type text}}),
    #"Inserted First Characters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Last Character", each Text.End([Avg], 1), type text),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted First Characters", "Start", each Text.Start([Avg], Text.Length([Avg])-1))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```